# How to debug try-runtime with the new try-runtime client?

Tags: try-runtime, debugging

I'm trying to attach the lldb debugger (from VS Code) to the new try-runtime client. However the breakpoints I setup inside the chain code on `on_upgrade` are never reached (Obliviously because they are running from wasm code)

launch.json:

```
    {
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug try runtime",
        "cargo": {
            "args": [
                "build",
                "--features",
                "try-runtime"
            ],
        }, 
        "program": "/home/user/.cargo/bin/try-runtime",
        "args": ["--runtime",
                 "./target/debug/wbuild/runtime-icecream/runtime_icecream.wasm",
                 "on-runtime-upgrade",
                 "snap",
                 "-p",
                 "snapshots/icecream"

    ],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
```

Is there any way I could setup the debugger to try-runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I solved this problem by chaining the point of view.* It is possible to attach a debugger to the [try-runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/try-runtime-cli) project and treat the chain code as a black box. Observing the input and the output gave me the relevant clues I needed.

```
git clone https://github.com/paritytech/try-runtime-cli.git
```

Link to the chain project from `launch.json` configuration file and debug with F5 as usual.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug executable 'try-runtime on-runtime-upgrade'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "--bin=try-runtime",
                    "--package=try-runtime-cli",
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "try-runtime",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [
                "--runtime",
                "/home/iceman/nodle/chain/target/release/wbuild/runtime-icecream/runtime_icecream.wasm",
                "on-runtime-upgrade",
                "snap",
                "-p",
                "/home/iceman/nodle/chain/snapshots/icecream"
                ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not without significant change to `try-runtime-cli`. Suggest using logging for your debug.